# Filtering long lists take a long time to run

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Dropdown with about 7000 objects. I have tried using semantic-ui react components but it still takes a long time to search and get results.

My copyList contains all the options and the filteredCopyList is what is rendered in the dropdown onKeyUp. Is it going slow due to rendering a long list of items and filtering them at the same time?

```
//list of 7000
const copyList = [
    {itemDesc: 'itemDesc1', shortDesc: 'shortDesc1'}
]


filterList = () => {
    const re = new RegExp(_.escapeRegExp(this.state.searchCopyList),'i');
    const isMatch = result => (re.test(result.shortDesc) || 
    re.test(result.itemDesc));
    this.setState({
        filteredCopyList: _.filter(this.state.copyList, isMatch)
    });
}
```

Comment: Seeing a list of 7000 items is not useful to anyone. You can't really process that many items in a meaningful way. Consider only rendering items after filtering, but that doesn't necessarily fix your perf issues.

Comment: RegExp is overkill if you're only doing substring matching. Consider using `String.prototype.indexOf` for a start.

Comment: And for that many items don't start filtering until a minimum number of characters have been input

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following package of npm:

[Infinite Scrolling package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinite-scroller)